# How can I determine the proportion of a certain colour of an image in R?

Tags: r, image-processing

I'm trying to write a script to distinguish the amount/surface area of coloured droplets from a white background of an image:

[image: bluedroplets.png]

I just started with defining the colours:

```
   red   <- as.vector(image[,,1])
   green <- as.vector(image[,,2])
   blue  <- as.vector(image[,,3])  
   white <- (red + green+ blue)
```

and to transform them to rgb chromatic coordinates (as suggested in Sonnentag et al. 2012; DOI: 10.1016/j.agrformet.2011.09.009):

```
   rcc <- red/white
   gcc <- green/white
   bcc <- blue/white
```

Since the droplets may have different colour depth I also created an "excess blue" (for blue droplets), which is also adapted to the paper above (there they use excessive green to describe canopy greeness)

```
   excess_blue <- (2*bcc - (rcc+gcc))
```

I may want to use density curves to determine colour thresholds and to obtain the share of blue coloured droplets of that image, but I don't know how to apply a code on that. Secondly, I would like to have another colour distinguished (e.g. red) in the same picture.

Thanks for your help!

Timo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a simple task, nor one you should attempt to do in base R unless you have a strong desire to reinvent many wheels!

Fortunately, there are some packages that can help. Since your task is similar to that faced in analysis of microscopic images of cells, a good place to start is in [the CRAN medical imaging task view page](https://cran.r-project.org/web/views/MedicalImaging.html)

Here you will find links to some useful packages, including `EBImage`, which is hosted on Bioconductor rather than CRAN, so you will have to install it using:

```r
install.packages("BiocManager")
BiocManager::install("EBImage")
```

I have adapted the examples given in the [EBImage introduction page](https://www.bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/vignettes/EBImage/inst/doc/EBImage-introduction.html) to your use case here.

First we load the package, and make sure we can read your image:

```r
library(EBImage)

dots <- readImage("~/blue_dots.png")
display(dots, method = "raster")
```

[image]

Looks fine. Now, since the dots are a greeny-blue, and the rest of the image is white, the channel with the highest contrast is going to be the red channel. Let's confirm this visually:

```
par(mfrow = c(2, 2))
plot(dots)
text(140, 140, "All", cex = 3)
plot(getFrame(dots, 1))
text(140, 140, "Red", cex = 3, col = "red")
plot(getFrame(dots, 2))
text(140, 140, "Green", cex = 3, col = "green")
plot(getFrame(dots, 3))
text(140, 140, "Blue", cex = 3, col = "blue")
par(mfrow = c(1, 1))
```

[image]

The channels all look highly correlated (in fact if you regress the green channel on the red channel you get an adjusted R squared of > 0.9).

We will therefore just use the red channel to find the dots. We extract the red channel with `getFrame` and find the optimum threshold using `otsu`:

```r
dots <- getFrame(dots, 1)
threshold <- otsu(dots)
thresh_dots <- dots < threshold
```

Now we make sure that this threshold has picked out our dots properly:

```
display(thresh_dots)
```

[image]

Again, this looks pretty good. Now we can try to count the dots, by asking the package to give each individual region its own number. We can check this has worked visually by giving different colours to all the non-connected regions:

```r
nmask <- watershed( distmap(thresh_dots), 5)
display(colorLabels(nmask))
```

[image]

Pretty! And fairly good according to casual inspection. You can see the difficulty of defining what a dot is if you look at the large "splatter" near the bottom of the image. Our algorithm has called this two spots, though an argument could be made that it is three or even four spots (and we could change the watershed parameter to alter this if it was important).

Now we can count the number of unconnected regions to give us the number of dots on the page:

```r
length(table(bwlabel(thresh_dots)))
#> [1] 1576
```

And we can get the proportion of our image that is above the threshold like this:

```
length(which(nmask > 0.5))/length(nmask)
#> [1] 0.134278
```

So, the number of blue dots on the image is around 1576, and the percentage of the image that is covered with blue dots is 13.43%.

<sup>Created on 2020-02-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>